# How to understand the "Relaxing the monotonicity assumption"

Tags: virtual-memory

### CSAPP 9.93 Allocator Requirements ans Goals

we use "peak utilization" to characterize how efficiently an allocator uses the heap. We are given some sequence of n allocate and free requests "R0, R1, R2....". If an application requests a block of p bytes , then the resulting allocated block has a payload of p bytes. After request R_k has completed, let the aggregated payload, denoted P_k, be the sum of the payloads of the currently allocated blocks, and let H_k denote the current(monotonically nondecreasing) size of the heap.

Then the peak utilization over the first k+1 requests , denoted by U_k, is given by U_k = max(Pi)/H_k ( i <= k)

"we could relax the monotonically nondecreasing assumption in our definition of U_k ans allow the heap to grow up and down by letting H_k be the high-water mark over the first k+1 requests."

How to understand "allow the heap to grow up and down by letting H_k be the high-water mark over the first k+1 requests"?

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone will be able to understand this sentence out of context. Why not ask your instructor? (But do you know what it means to "relax an assumption"? All I can gather is that there was some assumption about monotonicity, and now we are relaxing it.)

Comment: Please don't change the question. It invalidates previous comments (and indeed the title), which will not be helpful to other users of the site with the same question.

Comment: first to use stack overflow, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: For the second version of the question: It means exactly what it says. The definition of U_k assumes monotonicity. We can remove that requirement by changing the definition of H_k to " Let H_k be the high water mark over the first k+1 requests."

Comment: H_k is the size of heap. But after the "allocate and free requests", the heap can't decrease. It's oddly that by letting H_k be the high-water mark over the first k+1 requests we can make the heap grow down?

Comment: Suppose you allocate two blocks and then free both of them. Why shouldn't the heap size be allowed to go back down to zero?

Comment: the payload is zero, but the heap' size is not change

Comment: a dynamic memory allocator maintains an area of a process's virtual memory known as the "heap". For each process, the kernel maintains a variable "brk" that points to the top of heap. An allocator maintains the heap as a collection of various-size blocks. Each block is a contiguous chunk of virtual memory that is either allocated or free.

Comment: That's right. And if you decrease brk, your heap gets smaller. (Also, not all operating systems use brk. Even unix doesn't really use it any more. mmap is how people allocate memory from the operating system nowadays.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.